# finding the value of k in an equation

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

Find the value of k such that $f(x)=x^4-kx^3+kx^2+1$ is divisible by $d(x)=x+2$.

I tried using synthetic division for this problem and was  able to get up to the part where k ends up being$(17+8k)$. My teacher said I am halfway done, What's next?

Comment: What is $f(-2)$?

Comment: When you first start synthetic substation.-2 times 1 (or $x^4$) equals -2.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that $f(x)=(x-\alpha)g(x)$ if and only if $f(\alpha)=0$ ?

Comment: I haven't seen that before.

Comment: In English it goes by the (in my opinion, slightly deceptive) name of "[polynomial remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem)".

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Find the roots of $f(x)$ (by Ruffini, for example) and set $k$ in such a way that one of the roots is at $x=-2$. Then you know that $f(x)$ will have a factorization which will include a factor $(x+2)$

Answer (score 1):

A few hints to get you started:

If $f(x)$ is divisible by $x+2$ $\implies$ $f(-2) = 0$

Use this information to find values for $k$